# Passing an arraylist to a method

Tags: java, arraylist

While studying for my upcoming exam I came across this question. (Question 1 as a comment in the code)

```
public class List {    

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Song> songList = new ArrayList<Song>();
    }

    public void addSong(Song song) {
      //Q.1 implement the addSong method which adds a Song object to the cart
        Song aSong = new Song("A Song", 20);

    }

    public void getTotalSongs() {
       //Q.2 implement the getTotalSongs that returns the total number of songs in the

    }

    public void displayAllSongs() {
        //Q.3 implement the displayAllSongs method which prints all song titles in the cart

    }

    public double getTotalPurchuse() {

        for (List aList : songList.Song.getPrice()) {
            return aList;
        }

    class Song {

        private String title;
        private double price;

        Song(String title, double price) {
            this.title = title;
            this.price = price;
        }

        public String getTitle() {
            return title;
        }

        public double getPrice() {
            return price;
        }
    }
}
```

(So far I've only attempted question 1 but the other questions aren't an issue.)

Am I doing what the question requires? (i.e. `Song aSong = new Song("A Song", 20);`). I feel this is too easy and I should be using `ArrayName.Add();`. If this is the case how does one parse an `ArrayList` to another method? (NOTE I can't change that already exists, I can only add my own code as it's an exam).

Comment: You should not create  a new Song object in that method and shouldn't your `songList `be an instance variable in the class?

Comment: Your array should be declared as a field, not inside the main method, also the `addSong` method isn't correct, you should add the song to the arrayList like this:
`songList.add(song);`

Comment: Move songList outside of main() and in addSong(Song s) you should do songList.add(s);

Comment: As stated in the question i CANT change the code, its a given example in a past exam. All  i can do is add code to the methods therefore I cant remove anything in the main.

Comment: Then neither of the problems can be solvessince you will not be able to access the list of songs (`songList`) in any of the given methods so something is wrong with the code in the question or you have misunderstood the question. _Edit_ I just notice that for Q2 you are supposed to returned the number of songs in a method that returns void so this question is so poorly written.

Comment: The comment in the code mentions that you need to add songs to Cart. I feel the question is to implement Cart which you can define at class level instance variable and not worry about how to pass songList to given methods.

Comment: ill post screenshots of the Question from the exam here: https://i.imgur.com/wGe8Okr.png + https://i.imgur.com/oBSkE2v.png

Comment: And by looking at the screenshots it's obvious that you have misunderstood the question when implementing your own incorrect version of Cart. I suggest you delete this question and try to solve the problem yourself using the correct version of Cart as described in the second screenshot so that you might learn something for your exam.

Answer (score 0):

You should move `songList` to class scope, and use add method `songList.add(song);` to add `songList`

```
public class List {    
ArrayList<Song> songList = new ArrayList<Song>();
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Song aSong = new Song("A Song", 20);
    List test = new List();
    test.addSong(aSong);
    //check total song
    test.getTotalSongs(); //print out 1
}

public void addSong(Song song) {
  //Q.1 implement the addSong method which adds a Song object to the cart

    songList.add(song);
}

public void getTotalSongs() {
   //Q.2 implement the getTotalSongs that returns the total number of songs in the
   System.out.println(songList.size());

}

public void displayAllSongs() {
    //Q.3 implement the displayAllSongs method which prints all song titles in the cart

}

public double getTotalPurchuse() {
    //Q.4 implement the getTotalPurchuse method which returns the total purhucse for all songs in the cart
    return 0;
}
```

}

Also should move out Song as separate file

```
public class Song {

        private String title;
        private double price;

        Song(String title, double price) {
            this.title = title;
            this.price = price;
        }

        public String getTitle() {
            return title;
        }

        public double getPrice() {
            return price;
        }
    }
```

Comment: i tried that and it gets non-static variable cant be referenced from a static context for  Song aSong = new Song("A Song", 20);

Comment: did you move class Song outside List class?

Comment: Okay so in the fine print of the exam it says "Add your code at the places indicated. you are NOT allowed to add other code at other places in the class implementation. For instance, you are not allowed to add any code before Method addSong". meaning i cant create the object  where you've placed it :(

Answer (score -1):

This should be the answer for your problem

```
  public class List {    
        private List<Song> songList = new ArrayList<Song>();

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            List cart = new List();
            Song song = new Song("song", 3.4);
            cart.addsong(song);
            cart.displayAllSongs();
        }

        public void addSong(Song song) {
           //Q.1 implement the addSong method which adds a Song object to the cart
           songList.add(song);
        }

        public List<Song> getTotalSongs() {
           //Q.2 implement the getTotalSongs that returns the total number of songs in the
           return songList;
        }

        public void displayAllSongs() {
            //Q.3 implement the displayAllSongs method which prints all song titles in the cart
            System.out.println("List of all songs: " + songList);
        }

        public double getTotalPurchuse() {
            //Q.4 implement the getTotalPurchuse method which returns the total purhucse for all songs in the cart
            Iterator<Song> it = songList.iterator();
            double total = 0;
            while(it.hasNext()){
                Song next = it.next();    
                total += next.getPrice();
            }
            return total;
        }

        class Song {

            private String title;
            private double price;

            Song(String title, double price) {
                this.title = title;
                this.price = price;
            }

            public String getTitle() {
                return title;
            }

            public double getPrice() {
                return price;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: you change getTotalSongs(), he dont want change skeleton

Comment: but if there is in the method specification to return the songs list the method could not be void

Comment: Actually the code posted by OP is wrong but then again getTotalSongs() should return an int if you read the comment carefully. And you should also add a description on what the code in your answer does and how it solves the issue OP is having